# Rearrange index of models within a Marionette Composite View

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, marionette

Without rendering the composite view how to rearrange the index of models in the collection.

I have to sort the itemViews of a Composite View. I have used Jquery UI sortable plugin. It's working fine in the DOM but I want to reflect the rearrangement in the Backbone Collection also, with out rendering the Composite view.

Comment: isn't comparator of any use to you?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `comparator` on your `Collection`, and your Composite View will take care of the rendering itself:

**Example**

```
var Member = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '',
    credit: 0,
    memberSince: 0
  }
});

// Specify what field in the model to sort with:
var Members = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Member,
  comparator: 'credit'
});

// The comparator can also be a function:
var Members = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Member,
  comparator: function(model) { return model.get('memberSince'); }
});
```